# MKAnnotationView subclass with custom isSelected setter is not called

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I've subclassed `MKAnnotationView` and created a custom setter on the isSelected property, but it doesn't fire. I've tried doing the same on the isHighlighted property where it gets called as expected.

Logging isSelected from another function before and after a selection occurs fields `true` and `false` as expected.

Why isn't the setter called?

```
internal final class CustomView: MKAnnotationView {
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            print("selected: \(isSelected)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem—just override `setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)` instead.